# Spanish java.time.format.DateTimeParseException on time String

Tags: java, locale

I am attempting to use the Java 8 DateTimeFormatter class to parse a time string that is in Spanish. After several hours of searching, I cannot find any hints. The error being returned is:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '905 PM AST MARTES 7 AGOSTO 2018' could not be parsed at index 4

This seem to be the start of the 'PM' element.

Here is the relevant code:

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
builder.parseCaseInsensitive();
builder.appendPattern("hmm a z EEE d MMM yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter(new Locale("es", "PR"));

String spanishDate = "905 PM AST MARTES 7 AGOSTO 2018"
Instant issuanceInstant = Instant.from(formatter.parse(spanishDate));
```

I have tried formatting it differently, but this is a standard format used on meteorological messages that I need to parse. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the builder methods are chainable. You don't need a separate statement for each one.

Comment: Did you check what the am/pm symbols are in your Locale?  It's possible they're something other than AM and PM, in which case PM might not be understood.

Answer (score 3):

`EEE` and `MMM` are short form. You need to use 4 letters for full form:

```
hmm a z EEEE d MMMM yyyy
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. It still has the same error, but once that's solved, this would have probably been the next one.

Comment: I wonder if there is something specific to a machine involved? I'm just using the standard Java 8 libraries.

Comment: @MattDavis What version?

Comment: Interestingly, if I remove the PM, change to 24 hour time, and remove the 'a' from you suggested format String, it works. builder.appendPattern("HHmm z EEEE d MMMM yyyy"); String spanishDate = "2105 AST MARTES 7 AGOSTO 2018";

Comment: It appears I misspoke. The machine has been updated, and it's using the Java 10 libraries. jre-10.0.2

Answer (score 0):

After reverting to Java 8, the bug has disappeared. Thanks for the help everyone! I'll file a report against it.